# Powershell did not auto complete files in user path

Tags: windows, powershell, autocomplete, path

Is there a command to enable auto complete files in environmental PATH. I can auto complete files and folders in the current path, but cannot with files in my environmental path.

I've tried $env:path, and all the paths are there for sure.

Thanks!

Here is what I got:

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

Comment: I just checked on my machine with PoSh 3.0 and was able to get it working, my current working dir was C:\ and I was able to use tab-completion to have it show me a file in one of my $env:path folders. What version are you running?

Comment: I'll check it today.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas on this one, someone who has a better idea of the internals may be able to help. The only other thing I  can think of for troubleshooting purposes is trying another computer to see if it's the same. For the record, you can also get your version with the easy-to-remember ```Get-Host```.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least PowerShell 3.0 for this feature to work.